# How can I search for a component with specific key in React Developer Tools?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I'm currently using the React Developer Tools chrome extension to debug a component based on React Virtualized.

As you can see in the screenshot, I was able to highlight all the cells, but I can't figure out how can I find only a Cell that has a specific key value. It seems that the search input supports Regex.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to docs, right now react-dev-tools only allow searching by component names. Check [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools#search-bar).